# No output after inserting input in PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I created this file with colors and hex, then I put them in an array and printed. Now I would like to get as output the hex of the color in input inserted by an user. For example if the user writes "Black" I expect to get "#000000". This is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php

$chex = array("Black" => "#000000", "White" => "#FFFFFF", "Grey" => "#808080", "Dark Grey" => "#2F2F2F", "Ivory" => "#FFFFF0");

foreach($chex as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Color = " . $x . ", Hex = " . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}

function printHex($Color) {
    $chex2 = array("Black" => "#000000", "White" => "#FFFFFF", "Grey" => "#808080", "Dark Grey" => "#2F2F2F", "Ivory" => "#FFFFF0");
    return $chex2[$Color];
}
if(isset($_POST['Color'])) 
{ 
    printHex($_POST['Color']); 
}


?>

Color: <input type="text" name="Color"> <br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `printHex()` only returns the value, so you may need to do something like `echo printHex($_POST['Color']);`.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to do this, but nothing changed

Comment: You need to create a form element around your input and set its method to post. I suspect you're passing the value into $_GET instead of $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your are accessing `$_POST['Color']`. But you don't submit the value in `POST` method. So you need to add a form which submits the data in `POST method`.

```html
<form method='post'>

  Color: <input type="text" name="Color"> <br>

</form>
```

Then, Now the function `printHex($_POST['Color']);` is just returning the value not printing it. So need to print it.

```php
if(isset($_POST['Color'])) 
{ 
    echo printHex($_POST['Color']); 
}
```

**AND**

You don't need to define `$chex2` again. You can access `$chex` directly inside `printHex` function using `global`.

**Full Code Will Be Like**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php

$chex = array("Black" => "#000000", "White" => "#FFFFFF", "Grey" => "#808080", "Dark Grey" => "#2F2F2F", "Ivory" => "#FFFFF0");

foreach($chex as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Color = " . $x . ", Hex = " . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}

function printHex($Color) {
    global $chex;
    return $chex[$Color];
}

if(isset($_POST['Color'])) 
{ 
    echo printHex($_POST['Color']); 
}


?>

<form method='post'>

  Color: <input type="text" name="Color"> <br>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot, I've just a little problem now. When I look for an element in the array and press enter I get a white page...

Comment: I'm sorry but same problem